# How do i compare two columns in a dataframe, checking if they exist before?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a 5-level MultiIndex Dataframe with the following column level names :

```
names=['Point', 'Method', 'Site', 'Direction', 'Damping']
```

and index name `frequency`.

[image: Excel representation of the dataframe]

Each column is a spectrum and my goal is to compare different spectrums for each "Point".
More specifically, I want to compare for each point :

```py
df.loc[:,(Specific Point, 1, Big site, Horizontal, 0.05)
```

with

```py
df.loc[:,(Specific Point, 2, Small Site, Horizontal, 0.05)
```

Because this dataframe is the result of merging, the columns aren't always present, and there are additional Points that I need to compare based on different conditions.

My goal is to create a new dataframe with different columns specifying if: Spectrum B exceed Spectrum A at some point, if Spectrum B  max is greater than Spectrum A max etc.

The problem is that I don't know how to check if the columns I need to compare are present. If they aren't, the desired action would be to pass the point and start the next one.

I have tried creating a loop with the point names and than call the specific column, but because sometimes they aren't present, I get a `KeyError` indicating that the label is not present.

Comment: You could use something like `if col in df.columns: ...` where `col` is the label of the column you want check?

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer, I already tried what you wrote and the problem that I encountered is that the 'col' call in this if condition can fail when it's not present, leading to a KeyError and taking us back to the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succesfully solved my problem by using try, except in my loop, such as:

```py
try:
    # trying to call both columns needed, if fail then go to except.
    SpectrumA = df.loc[:,(Specific Point, 1, Big site, Horizontal, 0.05)
    SpectrumB = df.loc[:,(Specific Point, 2, Small Site, Horizontal, 0.05)
    # comparing both columns in case of success, and writing the result in a
    # new dataframe.
    spectrum_compare(newdf, i, SpectrumA, SpectrumB)

except KeyError as error:
    print(error)
```